# Overclocked CPU will occasional spike the frequency by several GHz

Tags: crash, overclocking, cpufreq

I followed a guide while doing my OC i5-8600k to increase the multiplier in BIOS and then test for stability. It's been fine for years, but a few months ago it started to thermal throttle. I dropped the OC down, cleaned out the case, and tested again until the temps were safe and stable. Recently I noticed something odd in HWMonitor while playing CoD: MW (2019).

[HWMonitor window showing odd CPU values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFQPa.png)

You can see the above image the CPU spiked up to 6000 MHz after playing CoD the prior night, which seems unrealistic at best and dangerous at worst. Another night my game crashed and HWMonitor reported the max CPU Frequnecy at 11000 MHz. Temps are stable at 70 degrees celsius under load.

I must admit my Google-Fu is pretty bad but I haven't been able to turn up anything like this. Its also hard for me to describe.

Does this phenomenom have a technical name or cause that I can use to find a solution?

Thanks in advace for reading and any suggestions.

Comment: Sounds like a software defect in HWInfo, have you confirmed, you are using the current version and additionally confirmed the behavior with other benchmarking software? Your CPU isn’t actually reaching 6.7 GHz

Comment: I am using HWMonitor version 1.46.0 Driver 154 with no updates available. The reporting spikes only appear when the CPU hits 100% usage. Watching a chrome video at 2x speed caused this. I tested my OC with Prime95, but I dont have any other software.

Comment: I was suggested to use HWInfo instead of HW monitor this may just be HW Monitor being weird after the PC sleeps.